# Best way of reviving a session?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm having issues with my web-application expiring the session too soon (not unexpected, just too soon for the type of system I am developing). My host doesn't allow changing the session expiration time.

So I was thinking, is there any way that I can (in ASP .NET MVC) for instance save my session variables in a form, so that when that form is somehow submitted or the page has changed, I can reset the session variables?

But with the above theory (if it's even a good theory), then how do I handle such stuff in my controllers? Or is there a better way to reach a session that is theoretically infinite?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are describing is the standard use-case for cookies.
If your variables don't need to be secure, then save each in a cookie (or, if you want to do it right, have a "session object" that you serialize in a cookie).

If your variables need to be secure, save them in a database or flat file and save the encrypted row id in the cookie.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot retrieve a session.  Once gone, it is gone (and that's good for security reasons).

However, you can keep the session from expiring:

http://weblogs.asp.net/stevewellens/archive/2009/06/09/ah-ah-ah-ah-staying-alive-staying-alive.aspx